# Is there a "left-right" counterpart to "upside down", "inside-out" and "front to back"?

Tags: phrase-requests

(Source: [Merriam-Webster](http://www.merriam-webster.com))

Inside out

> in such a manner that the inner surface becomes the outer - *turned the shirt inside out*

Upside down

> in such a way that the upper and the lower parts are reversed in position

Front to back

> with the front where the back should be :  backwards - *He accidentally put the sweater on front to back.*

**QUESTION:** Is there an analogical "left-right" counterpart with the meaning of

> with the left where the right should be (and vice versa)

My primary use case is telling ones' kids they put on their clothes, shoes or gloves in a wrong way.

Comment: @Honda Zidek "left-right flip flop"?

Comment: @Kris do you mean lateral inversion?

Comment: A handy (little pun there) word to know in this context is chirality. It is not the word you want, but is useful when discussing left-right reversal.

Comment: One could also humorously say 'a reflection in the y-axis', or 'reflected in the y-axis'.

Comment: Flip-flopped or mirror image.

Comment: @SGR Thanks, I was typing too fast and didn't check back.

Comment: See: "lateral inversion;" "mirror image;" "?flipped sideways" -- Have fun!

Comment: What's wrong with "Hey, << insert name >>, your shoes are on the wrong feet." ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, you can use [*laterally-inverted*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Plane_mirror), as Kris and SGR note in comments.

If you want something closer to the tone of your other examples, try *about* (i.e. 'turn about', to parallel 'turn inside-out').

> **Turn about** *phrasal verb*
>   Move so as to face in the opposite direction: *Alice turned about and walked down the corridor*
>   [- ODO](http://www.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/english/turn#turn__197)

Note that just as turning something *upside-down* can also involve moving the left to the right, turning something *about* can do the same.

Think of the XYZ axes with +X pointing to you, +Y pointing to the right and +Z pointing straight up. Start with someone staring down the +X axis at you and right hand pointing towards -Y.

If we rotate them 180 degrees about the X axis, they will end up *upside-down*, but with their right hand now pointing towards +Y.

If we reset and now rotate 180 degrees about the Z axis, they are now *turned about*, again with their right hand pointing towards +Y.

For a more informal term with socks, shoes, gloves and the like, you can say (e.g.) "Your gloves are *swapped*". Here's an example in use in an informal context:

> Can confirm, first time I used surgery gloves put them on the wrong way around and was wondering why it didn't fit right, had to swap them quickly.
>   [- geliduss](https://www.reddit.com/r/funny/comments/3i3len/the_new_guy_at_work_asked_where_the_box_of_right/cudas2a)

You can also use *switched* instead of *swapped*:

> **Switched** *verb*
>   1.2 Substitute (two items) for each other; exchange
>   [- ODO](http://www.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/english/switch?q=switched#switch__12)

Comment: Well, my primary use case is putting on your clothes and shoes.

Comment: @HonzaZidek In that case, *swapped* is idiomatic. If this fits, let me know and I'll edit it into my answer.

Comment: Yes. Is the usage like "you have put on your shoes swapped" (based on "you have put on your t-shirt front to back")?

Comment: It's more like "Your shoes are swapped."

Comment: Actually, where I come from*, we say "Your shoes are on backwards."  That does not mean that the front of the shoe is at the back of your foot.  It means what it has to mean:  left shoe on right foot and vice versa.  You can also say "Your shoes are on the wrong feet."  But the other person can counter, "Whose feet should they be on?"    ----       *New York

Comment: @HonzaZidek "Well, my primary use case is putting on your clothes and shoes." -- better include that in the body of the question for everyone's notice.

Answer (score 0):

Another term would be ***[Reversed](http://www.dictionary.com/browse/reversed)***:

1. opposite or contrary in position, direction, order, or character:
   an impression reverse to what was intended; in reverse sequence.
2. with the back or rear part toward the observer:
   the reverse side of a fabric.
3. pertaining to or producing movement in a mechanism opposite to that made under ordinary running conditions:
   a reverse gear; a reverse turbine.
4. acting in a manner opposite or contrary to that which is usual, as an appliance or apparatus.
5. noting or pertaining to an image like that seen in a mirror; backward; reversed.
6. noting or pertaining to printed matter in which what is normally white, as the page of a book, appears as black, and vice versa.

Answer (score 0):

**Mirrored**. A reflection transform about a (vertical) plane or axis produces a mirror image of the original. The verb is mirror. In 3D, you can use a reflection plane to create a new 3D image, which is exactly what an actual mirror does, or you can use a reflection line to create a mirrored image that is both left to right and front to back mirrored. It's a bit more general and context dependent that what you want. A mountain's reflected image on the surface of a lake is upside down, but still called a mirror image. But by analogy to a mirror hanging on a wall, if you just say mirror image, the canonical example is left-right reversal.

> something that ​looks ​exactly the same as another thing but with ​its
>   ​left and ​right ​sides in ​opposite ​positions: His ​home is two
>   ​terraced ​houses ​knocked together, each the ​mirror ​image of the
>   other.

Cambridge Dictionaries online: mirror image http://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/mirror-image